# on changing device orientation listview gets re-created

Tags: android, listview, orientation, indexoutofboundsexception

In my application there is a listview which dynamically increases by 10 items every time i scroll down to the bottom. so while using portrait orientation i scroll down to 100 items and then when i change the orientation to landscape my listview is getting created again (shows only first 10 items). The problem here is when i go back to portrait app crashes saying:

```
06-06 12:06:54.849: E/AndroidRuntime(4684): java.lang.RuntimeException:
Unable to start activity 
ComponentInfo{com.Android.MyApp/com.Android.MyApp.ListViewActivity}:
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

how to make the listview restore even on changing the orientation???

Comment: To stop recreation add in manifest file `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` in your activity tag.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is happening because your activity is getting re-created on orientation change.
 
To avoid it, add this in your `AndroidManifest.xml` under your activity tag:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

and include this method in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
```

Hope it helps !!!

Comment: It is not needed to implement onConfigurationChanged if you're not going to change anything (which is normally not needed if you're just switching from landscape to portrait and having a wrap_content ListView)

Comment: Yes... But if u need to modify any control position size/position based on orientation change, so this method will be needed. So no harm in implementing it.

Comment: and newConfig in the onConfigurationChanged must be orientation??? or just the newConfig?

Comment: it's just an object name. use same in 1st and 2nd line. You can use whatever u want. You may use exact same method as suggested in answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choices.

**Option 1**

Include `android:configChanges="orientation"` two prevent activity restart 
But this will prevent you from setting up different UI for Different Orientation.

**Option 2**

If you want to setup different UI for Different Orientations Then you will have to write 
bit more code.

Read onSaveInstanceState and `onRestoreInstanceState` to save and retrieve values while
restarting activity.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is pretty simple: You have to change your Activity's AndroidManifest-entry and add

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

This one will make sure that if an orientation change happens your Activity doesn't get recreated.

Make sure to override the [onConfigurationChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onConfigurationChanged%28android.content.res.Configuration%29) method to react to the change (if you want to react ;))

Comment: and what must be implemented in the onConfigurationChanged....to say not to restart the activity??

Comment: There is already a super implementation existant - you don't need to override it if you're just calling super ;)

Comment: saved me a lot of time :-) +1